# Folder not opening in Spring Tool Suite after changing folder name

Tags: java, spring, spring-tool-suite

Does anyone know how to retrieve a Java project after changing the folder name outside Spring Tool Suite? I didnt use the refactor feature and I instead just changed the name in my folder directory. I didn't realize it would make such impact. None of the files under that particular project are viewable. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse (and Spring Tool Suite) IDE has project files that it uses to control files and folders.
This project files are created when you import the project and changed when you do changes inside the IDE.

If you do some change outside the IDE without updating project files, IDE may not recognize it depending on the files or folder edited.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to delete the project in your IDE and choose to not delete the files on your hard drive while doing that (there is a dialog showing up when you delete a project in the IDE asking you this).

Then, re-import the project from the changed folder using the import wizard for importing "Already existing projects into workspace".